# How do I keep my form elements from moving when I resize my window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to make my form element (pops up when I click add book) stay static on the page. When I resize my browser window it reduces and the elements within spill out beyond the div. I am not using flex box for this container (only for isRead because I couldn't center it), what is causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thank you in advance.

Screen-shots for reference below:

*Full size browser window*

[image]

*Resizing of form when scaling window down*

[image]

```js
// User interface //
const popUpForm = document.querySelector(".form-popup");
const button = document.querySelector("#addBook");
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

// Form Pop Up function //
document.getElementById('invisibleDiv').onclick = function() {
  popUpForm.style.display = "none";
  overlay.style.display = "none";
};

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popUpForm.style.display = "block";
  overlay.style.display = "block";
});

const updateBooksGrid = () => {
  resetBooksGrid()
  for (let book of library.books) {
    createBookCard(book)
  }
}
```

```css
/*CSS RESET*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 8vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

.head-box {
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20vh;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e0f3ff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 5vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

h3 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 4vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

button {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 20vh;
  min-width: 20vh;
  min-height: 10vh;
  font-size: 3vh;
  background-color: #27476E;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border-style: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #192c44;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #d0edff, #9DD1F1) no-repeat;
}

.body-box {
  margin: 3vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* The pop up form - hidden by default */

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9;
}

.form-content {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 30vh;
  height: 43vh;
  border: 3px solid #001D4A;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  gap: 10px;
}

.form-container {
  min-width: 20vh;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.isRead {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d0edff;
  border: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#submit {
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#invisibleDiv {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.books-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.book-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!----------Font Below ---------------->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/jmq2vxa.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/open-book.png" />
  <title>My Library</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="head-box">
    <h1>My Library</h1>
  </div>
  <main class="main-container">
    <div class="body-box">
      <button id="addBook">Add Book</button>
    </div>
    <div class="books-grid" id="booksGrid"></div>
  </main>
  <!-----Form information----->
  <div class="form-popup">
    <div class="form-content" <form action="example.com/path" class="form-container" id="popUpForm">
      <h3>add new book</h3>
      <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title">
      <input type="author" id="author" placeholder="Author">
      <input type="pages" id="pages" placeholder="Pages">
      <div class="isRead">
        <label for="readOption">Have you read it?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="readOption" name="readOption">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="invisibleDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: All of your font-sizes are in`vh` which changes whenever the viewport height changes. Use a static unit like `px` instead. Also, this happens with anything with intrinsic units (`vh`,`vw`,`vmin`, and `vmax`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with your CSS. You can solve it by changing your height to auto in your container:

```
.form-content {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 30vh; 
    height: auto;
    border: 3px solid #001D4A;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #9DD1F1;
    gap: 10px;
```

}